# Add "backup" option when uploading to Cloudinary using Carrierwave

Tags: carrierwave, cloudinary

I created a Carrierwave uploader to Cloudinary following guidelines here http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_carrierwave

It looks like this :

```
class MatePictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  def public_id
    "mate/picture/#{model.id}" 
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [110, 110, :north]
  end

end
```

Now I would like to pass the "backup" upload option so that cloudinary keep a version of it (I don't want to activate the option globally on my Cloudinary account).

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options can be passed to Cloudinary using the `cloudinary_transformation` method.

For the "backup" option, it would look like this :

```
class MatePictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  cloudinary_transformation backup: true

  def public_id
    "mate/picture/#{model.id}" 
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [110, 110, :north]
  end

end
```